# Regex to extract data from card swipe

Tags: c#, regex

I'm searching for a regular expression that will extract `0263563`

from

```
;010263563=2119?
```

and `0267829`

from

```
%00000026782904?;010267829=4119?
```

(Must be the same regular expression).

Comment: How both are related?

Comment: Ignore everything pre semicolon and strip the first 2 digits?

Comment: Are `;010`, `=2119`, `%00000` and `04?;010267829=4119?` constant parts? Do they change? What would be a human-language description of how the data is assembled? Something like "the string starts with three numbers, then followed by 10, which I'm interested in, then followed by..."

Comment: Maybe if you put into words the rule that identifies the string that you want to extract, it will be easier (for you or for us) to come up with the appropriate regex.

Comment: Yes, sorry, here it is:  Start at the 3rd character after the semicolon and take 7 characters.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be a regular expression, or will you be fine with other options that provide the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the very fast answer!  Ended up using M42's expression though several posted here worked.  Did need a regular expression (as opposed to other solution).  The expression goes in configuration data so that the code doesn't have to be touched for each new client's card layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Start at the 3rd character after the semicolon and take 7 characters.

```
;..(\d{7})
```

or more general:

```
;..(.{7})
```

Or according to comment : "To clarify characters to take are digits"

```
;\d\d(\d{7})
```

Comment: He doesn't said the characters to take are digits either :p

Comment: To clarify characters to take are digits.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would exactly 7 digits which must be preceded by a `;` , any two characters.

```
(?<=;.{2})\d{7}
```

Code:

```
String input = @";010263563=2119?
%00000026782904?;010267829=4119?";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=;.{2})\d{7}");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Vd5LFT)

Output:

```
0263563
0267829
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need this:

```
;\d{2}(\d+)
```

The First group will contain the number you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
;[\S]{2}([\S]{7})
```

Since you said characters and not numbers, but it would work either way

Answer (score 1):

For rules that are that precise (start 3 chars after `;`, then next 7), you could use a plain substring:

```
string s = "%00000026782904?;010267829=4119?";
var pos = s.IndexOf(';');
var number = s.Substring(pos+3, 7);
```

And of course, test whether that IndexOf really found the ;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming regex is not an absolute requirement, you could use:

```
var input = "%00000026782904?;010267829=4119?";

// output will be: 0267829
var digits = input.SkipWhile(x => x != ';').Skip(3).Take(7).ToArray();
var output = new string(digits);
```